# OpenStack Swift : add Cache-Control and Expires headers

Tags: http-headers, openstack, openstack-swift

I have file objecs stored in an OpenStack Swift container, and I can specify the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers with the POST object requests.

Yet, I'm not capable to set the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` header to control so browsers would keep the files in cache —the files are mostly thumbnails, logos and background images that must be cached by end browsers.

I noticed that containers accept a `X-Container-Read` to allow public access of files, but I found nothing related to cache control at the container level neither.

So, is it possible to set the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` headers (or any custom header), either at the object or container level in OpenStack Swift? I mean, without requiring a CDN or a proxy server in-between?

Answer (score 3):

Openstack swift can handle cache expiration with no problem at all. The only thing required is that HTTP headers are used appropriately.

For example, to limit cache validity to a week max, you only need to set a header for 'Cache-Control' like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'X-Auth-Token: YOURTOKEN' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800' https://openstack/container/object
```

Or if you use the swift client, like this:

```
swift post --header 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800' <container> <object>
```

To test that it works:

```
curl -I https://openstack/container/object
```

As per the HTTP/1.1 definition for [Cache-Control](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3):

- You don't need to specify 'public' when setting max-age. But you may also do 'Cache-Control: public', or a bit redundant 'Cache-Control: public, max-age=6064800'
- I've not found a way to specify 'Expires' headers, however these are not really necessary. According to the definition, if Cache-Control max-age is specified, this would override Expires in any case.
- This all would apply to HTTP/1.1. If pre-historic clients using HTTP/1.0 are used, then there may still be the possibility of using a Pragma header using the same API method.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own question: there is no way to set the `Cache-Control` and `Expires` HTTP headers on OpenStack Swift objects.

Yet, it doesn't mean that files aren't cached by browsers:

- Swift correctly sets the `Etag` and `Last-Modified` HTTP headers, so browsers won't request the file again, unless we reload or force-reload the page. As long as the URL are stable, of course, either using a fixed tempurl expiry date or with the `X-Container-Read` header set on the container.
- Swift also handles the `Last-Modified-Since` request header with a `304 Not Modified` response when the page is reloaded, so the contents won't be downloaded again, unless they changed.

Comment: but iPhone needs Expires and Cache-Control headers for them not to redownload again. Is there anyway to set it at all?

Comment: I really found no way. Maybe running a cache CDN like cloudfront or cloudflare in front of a public Swift container would help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

By adding Cache-Control and Expires to allowed_headers list in object-server.conf, you can set those two headers in POST requests to objects.

Tested on OpenStack Swift Pike.